# exclude related column text from index to avoid combined matches

Tags: discussion, seo

Sometimes a search result only matches all the search terms because one of the terms is in the text of the related column.

#### Example

The search [[evil whitespace mode dollar]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=evil+whitespace+mode+dollar) currently has [whitespace-mode in minibuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972485/whitespace-mode-in-minibuffer) as it's 3rd  result, but only because the question [Keep Emacs Evil from switching to normal mode when exiting minibuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915532/keep-emacs-evil-from-switching-to-normal-mode-when-exiting-minibuffer?rq=1) is in the related column and has the word `evil` in it. Neither are good results for those search terms.

#### <strike>Solution</strike>

The text of the releated column could be excluded if is was wrapped in `<!--googleoff: index-->` and `<!--googleon: index-->`

https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/46/admin_crawl/Preparing#pagepart

**Edit:** botther! that's only for google search appliance. Is there a way to do this for google website search?

Comment: These tags only work with the google appliance/google mini - they don't effect the search engine.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that after I posted the question

Comment: Would the related column still be indexed if it was lazy-loaded?

Comment: Probably not, but Google could penalize us for such practices.

Comment: What about putting it in an iframe that shows a page from a directory that's excluded in robots.txt? e.g. `<iframe src="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/related/221981" />`

Comment: Also, I wonder if the iframe [srcdoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc) atribute was used to provide the content inline so an extra request wasn't needed, would google still exclude the content?

Comment: Google essentially penalizes sites for showing different content to the search engine and users - this is not something that can be just done lightly.

Comment: @Oded you can serve `<iframes src="..." srcdoc=".." />` to everyone: http://jsfiddle.net/JWeeh/ the question is just whether google will ignore the content if the url in `src` is disallowed by `robots.txt`. It's a testable hypothesis.